# How can I check if it is complete data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a server that is receiving data from a client device. The client will send data to server and it always end up 3 characters, e.g. `*46`.

How can I check if the data ends with an asterisk and 2 characters, so that I will know that this is the complete data from my client?

Furthermore, the device may append a newline at the end of thedata, so how do I also check if there is newline at the end of data?

Here is my code so far:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
   socket.on('data', function(data) {
       var receivedata = data.toString();
      // How to check if received data is complete, i.e. ending in 3 characters, *23
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this. Here are a couple of links to help start you off:

- [Node.js: Regular Expression To Get "From: " and "To: "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675315/node-js-regular-expression-to-get-from-and-to)
- http://javascript.info/tutorial/regular-expressions-methods
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

The actual regex expression you'll want is:
***[0-9]{2}$**

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx. For an example :

```
var str = "Hello wor*23";
if(str.match(/\*[0-9][0-9]$/)){
  console.log("Hello");
}
else{
  console.log("Data not proper");
}
```

It checks if the last 3 values are `* number number`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this

As long as the data is a chunk of a stream, you need to wait for the `end` event to get the complete data

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
   var receivedata = "";
   socket.on('data', function(data) {
      receivedata += data.toString();
   });
   socket.on('end', function() {
      console.log(receivedata);
   });
});
```

**Note** *untested*